# Connect to a VPN with a password from the commandline

Tags: command-line, network-manager, vpn, automation

I can trigger the start of connection to my VPN by saying

```
nmcli con up id WORKVPN
```

But I have an RSA SecurID that is part of the authentication, which means I can't store a password.  Without a password, Network Manager pops up a GUI prompt.  I would like to be able to pass the password in or at least be prompted on the commandline instead of the GUI.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what kind of vpn are you using? ipsec, openvpn? nmcli is probably just wrapping around another command line tool.

Comment: @noleti I am using OpenConnect.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest couple of options

- sshpass (Caution: I haven't tried myself, and it is not secure if someone is looking over your shoulder or goes through your history)

  ```
  sshpass -p vpnpassword <your command>
  ```

It works with SSH connection, give it a try.

- A more practical and somewhat safer approach. Take a look at [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/), which installation in Ubuntu is as easy as

  ```
  sudo apt-get install expect
  ```

  Write a wrapper script, use expect inside your bash script

  ```
  expect <<- DONE
  expect "<put here what you see in your password prompt> "
  send "<vpn password>\n"
  interact
  DONE
  ```

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what I need.  It assumes that the command will ask for the password in the shell (which is what I want it to do). The problem I am trying to solve is that it asks for the password in a popup window in X.

Comment: Then in that case, look for GUI automation tools to script that. Something like Autoit.

Answer (score 0):

These commands work for me:

```
XAUTH="$(ps -C Xorg -o args= | sed -n 's/.*-auth \(.*\)/\1/p')"
export XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH
export DISPLAY=:0.0
XUSER="$(ps -C nm-applet -o user=)"
su ${XUSER} -c "nmcli c up 'VPN'"
```